# Two problems with scrollbar in List component

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

1. I want to hide/remove the up and down arrows from the scrollbar - how can i do that?
2. the scrollbar is to fat - the skin i am using is not that fat. How can i make the scrollbar thiner.

thanks

Comment: What version of Flex SDK are you using? MX or Spark scrollbars?

Comment: For Spark scroller there is a clean and simple solution: http://riatiger.com/blog/2012/06/spark-scroller-skinning/

Answer (score 0):

```
    /*CSS*/

   HScrollBar{
    up-arrow-skin: ClassReference( null );
    down-arrow-skin: ClassReference( null );
    }
    VScrollBar{
    up-arrow-skin: ClassReference( null );
    down-arrow-skin: ClassReference( null );
    }
```

[image]
[image]

hi, i you have to do this , as u can see in view1, the btns r thr, in view2, they r removed as i have put this css.

and as far as sknning is concerned u need to have proper skins, make it a bit smaller, mine is thumb is too not smooth

n e ways, i hope it helps, tc

Ankur Sharma